# Receive GCM notification without Android

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, amazon-sns, pyhook

Is it possible to receive GCM notification from Amazon sns without Android? I.e. to email, python.
In other word, is it possible to emulate Android gcm client?

Comment: You can pass the data payload emulating the GCM payload via Amazon SNS. But other default GCM keys will not be available.

Comment: FCM sdk is available for [JS receivers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive) too.

Comment: @Darshan Pania, thank you. Amazon sns can send GCM, but how to receive it without Android app? For example in bdd tests...

Comment: Do you mean Behavior Driven Development test cases?

Comment: @Darshan Pania, yes

Comment: If you receive the GCM look-alike payload via SNS, then all your client needs to do is have a parser code which parses the payload. You will obviously not be able to render a push notification without the Android environment